# 2 simple "unresolved identitier" errors that I can't fix in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I am a Swift beginner currently following an Apple Intro to Developing iOS Apps in Swift tutorial. I have the follow error codes " Use of unresolved identifier 'UIImagePickerController' " and "Use of unresolved identifier 'imagePickController' " on lines 3 and 4 respectively. Thanks in advance!

```
@IBAction func selectionImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    let imagePickerController = UIIMagePickerController()

    imagePickController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    imagePickerController.delegate=self

    presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Comment: syntax error. you capitalized letter M in UIImagePickerController

Comment: ... and you use `imagePickController` after declaring `imagePickerController`. Sadly, spelling accuracy is important in every language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully you have two syntax errors:

1. It's `UIImagePickerController` not `UIIMagePickerController`
2. You're declaring a constant called `imagePickerController` and after that you're using `imagePickController`.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hey Victor, I see it now thanks!

Comment: @bwang You're welcome, please accept the answer if it solve your question